# Stream video and audio frames from YouTube

Tags: python, video, youtube, streaming, vlc

I am trying to stream video and audio data from a YouTube video so that I can do some video and audio analysis seperately which is then superimposed on the frames using OpenCV. I have this working perfectly fine with files but want to extend this to streaming from YouTube.

At the moment, I've thought of usings VLC Python bindings to stream from YouTube but I'm not sure how to extract the frames from this video.

Here is the vlc code that performs YouTube streaming at the moment:

```
import vlc
import time
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *

class MyDisplay(vlc.VideoDisplayCb):
    def __doc__(o,p):
        print "fsdfs"

class MyLock(vlc.VideoLockCb):
    def __doc__():
        raise Exception("sdsds")
        return np.array(500,500).__array_interface__['data']

class MyPlayback(vlc.AudioPlayCb):
    def from_param(self,a,b,c,d):
        print "asfds"

def callbck(a,b,c,d):
    print 'aa'
    print a 
    print b
    print c
    print d
    return 'a'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F82XtLmL0tU'
    i = vlc.Instance('--verbose 2'.split())
    media = i.media_new(url)
    media_list = i.media_list_new([url])

    p = i.media_player_new()
    p.set_media(media)

    lp = i.media_list_player_new()
    lp.set_media_player(p)
    lp.set_media_list(media_list)
    CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_char, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_uint, c_long)

    lp.next()
    lock = MyLock()
    display = MyDisplay()

    playback = MyPlayback()
    p.audio_set_callbacks(CMPFUNC(callbck),None,None,None,None,None)
    p.play()

    time.sleep(5)
    r = p.video_take_snapshot(0,'rnd.pong',0,0)
```

How could I produce a stream of frames and audio data using VLC (with Python bindings)? Also is there another way to do this (using ffmpeg for example)?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Would be interested in learning how!

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry for the long reply delay!